# How to release a semaphore and let any threads continue?

Tags: java, multithreading, semaphore

I want to create a semaphore that prevents a certain method to be executed more than 1x at a time.

If any other thread requests access, it should wait until the semaphore is released:

```
private Map<String, Semaphore> map;

public void test() {
    String hash; //prevent to run the long running method with the same hash concurrently
    if (map.contains(hash)) {
        map.get(hash).aquire(); //wait for release of the lock
        callLongRunningMethod();
    } else {
        Semaphore s = new Semaphore(1);
        map.put(hash, s);
        callLongRunningMethod();
        s.release(); //any number of registered threads should continue
        map.remove(hash);
    }
}
```

Question: how can I lock the semaphore with just one thread, but release it so that *any* number of threads can continue as soon as released?

Some clarifications:

Imagine the long running method is a transactional method. Looks into the database. If no entry is found, a heavy XML request is send and persisted to db. Also maybe further async processed might be triggered as this is supposed to be the "initial fetch" of the data. Then return the object from DB (within that method). If the DB entry had existed, it would directly return the entity.

Now if multiple threads access the long running method at the same time, all methods would fetch the heavy XML (traffic, performance), and all of them would try to persist the same object into the DB (because the long running method is transactional). Causing eg non-unique exceptions. Plus all of them triggering the optional async threads.

When all but one thread is locked, only the first is responsible for persisting the object. Then, when finished, all other threads will detect that the entry already exists in DB and just serve that object.

Comment: Why not just put the `callLongRunningMethod` in a `synchronized(this) { ... }` block? Or `synchronized (hash)`? (Or make `callLongRunningMethod` itself `synchronized`, if it's not private and/or is called from somewhere else other than this method)

Comment: where is `hash` supposed to come from and what is it's intention?

Comment: Because the method might be running concurrently *if* the hash is different. I may just not for the same hash value.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "any number of threads can continue as soon as released". You what multiple reads after single write per hash?

Comment: Exactly. Any threads that are **in waiting state** while the lock is active, they all may continue concurrently when the lock is released. In spite, when I new thread enters and the map has no lock for the hash, a new hash should be created, blocking any concurrent threads with the same hash

Comment: "they all may continue concurrently when the lock is released" So are you saying that if Threads 1, 2, 3 call `test` at the same time, T1 will prevent T2 and T3 from calling the method, but when T1 completes, T2 and T3 can call the method concurrently?

Comment: Another case: T1 calls `test` and the long-running method completes, releasing the lock; subsequently, T2 and T3 call `test` concurrently - should they do anything with the lock?

Comment: @AndyTurner you got it right. But if T4 comes in with the same hash, and T1 already completed, but T2 + T3 are still active, then T4 of course should create a new lock. As T2+T3 have been waiting on T1 already, non of them should create a lock.

Comment: @membersound that is *really* strange behaviour.

Comment: @AndyTurner see my clarification update

Comment: @membersound what should happen when hash is removed, blocked thread started processing and a new Thread would come having the same hash?

Comment: If a thread comes whose hash is not yet contained, it should just create a new lock.

Comment: @membersound you mean that after " map.remove(hash);" it should create a new lock or after all reader threads are done ?

Comment: It would be fine if it creates a new lock while other threads are running (due to a previous release).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I understand your need you want to be able to ensure that the task is executed by one single thread for the first time then you want to allow several threads to execute it if so you need to rely on a `CountDownLatch` as next:

Here is how it could be implemented with `CountDownLatch`:

```
private final ConcurrentMap<String, CountDownLatch> map = new ConcurrentHashMap<>(); 

public void test(String hash) {
    final CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
    final CountDownLatch previous = map.putIfAbsent(hash, latch);
    if (previous == null) {
        try {
            callLongRunningMethod();
        } finally {
            map.remove(hash, latch);
            latch.countDown();
        }
    } else {
        try {
            previous.await();
            callLongRunningMethod();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `Semaphore s = map.computeIfAbsent(hash, k -> new Semaphore(1));` is easier in Java 8+.

Comment: Wouldn't `s.release()` just return the count of locks back (which are `1` here)?  I want to allow any waiting threads to continue, not just 1.

Comment: @membersound You mean the waiting thread doesn't execute the task at all, they only wait until it is done?

Comment: I do want any waiting threads to wait for the main thread to finish. Then any waiting threads may thereafter run the longRunningMethod concurrently as soon as the lock is released.

Comment: 1) Thread 1 calls the method. No lock is found, so it creates another, calls the long-running method (LRM); waits. 2) Thread 2 calls the method. Lock is found, so it waits on calling LRM. 3) Thread 1's call to LRM completes. It releases the lock, so Thread 2's call to LRM starts. Thread 1 removes the lock from the map. (Note that Thread 2's LRM call hasn't finished). 4) Thread 1 calls the method again. No lock is found, so it creates another, calls the long-running method (LRM) - *Both thread 1 and thread 2 invoking LRM at the same time for the same hash*. http://ideone.com/aCuopK

Comment: @AndyTurner that's correct, it should be done with a FutureTask instead of a Semaphore to avoid this

Comment: I cannot use `FutureTask` to wrap the longRunningMethod, as this destroys several things like hibernate session, transaction etc.

Comment: @membersound I added a "Response Update" please check if it is what you need

Comment: I would want to avoid having to call the long running method from within the lock object inside a new runnable task. But apart from that it looks just fine. `CountDownLatch` looks promising, maybe I can use that in spite of my initial semaphore.

Comment: Why would you need to call `callLongRunningMethod()` twice?

Comment: @membersound but you need a State otherwise how could you know if the task has already been called?

Comment: @NicolasFilotto I downvoted previously because your answer didn't work, for the reasons I described. And I'm still going to leave it there (for now) because this doesn't work after the second call for a given hash.

Comment: @AndyTurner I removed the first part of the answer as it is not what he wanted so your reason is no more applicable

Comment: @membersound I applied your remarks and implemented it with CountDownLatch

Comment: @AndyTurner I don't remove the entries manually anymore, I rely on a ConcurrentMap with weak values built with Google Guava

Answer (score 2):

As far as I understand, you don't need to use `Semaphore` here. Instead, you should use `ReentrantReadWriteLock`. Additionally, the `test` method is not thread safe.

The sample below is the implementation of your logic using RWL

```
private ConcurrentMap<String, ReadWriteLock> map = null;

void test() {
    String hash = null;
    ReadWriteLock rwl = new ReentrantReadWriteLock(false);
    ReadWriteLock lock = map.putIfAbsent(hash,  rwl);

    if (lock == null) {
        lock = rwl;
    }

    if (lock.writeLock().tryLock()) {
        try {
            compute();
            map.remove(hash);
        } finally {
            lock.writeLock().unlock();
        }
    } else {
        lock.readLock().lock();
        try {
            compute();
        } finally {
            lock.readLock().unlock();
        }
    }
}
```

In this code, the first successful thread would acquire `WriteLock` while other `Thread`s would wait for release of write lock. After release of a `WriteLock` all `Thread`s waiting for release would proceed concurrently.

Comment: Note: your approach isn't thread-safe either because the sequence of calls to `map.get` and `map.put` isn't atomic.

Comment: One more question: when `lock != null`, I would want the thread to *wait* for the lock to be released. What you did is applying a `readLock`, which is not what I want. As soon as the lock is released, any waiting threads should be able to continue concurrently. They should just pause while writing to the lock is active.

Comment: Are you certain that you always want to remove the hash from the map in the `else` case?

Comment: Yes I always want to remove the hash after the lock is released.

Comment: 1) Thread 1 calls the method. No lock is found, so it creates another, calls the long-running method (LRM); waits. 2) Thread 2 calls the method. Lock is found, so it waits on calling LRM. 3) Thread 1's call to LRM completes. It releases the lock, so Thread 2's call to LRM starts. Thread 1 removes the lock from the map. (Note that Thread 2's LRM call hasn't finished). 4) Thread 1 calls the method again. No lock is found, so it creates another, calls the long-running method (LRM) - *Both thread 1 and thread 2 invoking LRM at the same time for the same hash*.

Comment: @AndyTurner what do you think about this updated answer?

Comment: @membersound I've updated the answer. This time this is my last update :)

Comment: I think that your solution could be made simpler: the if/else is basically identical, save the remove. If you do `map.values().remove(lock)` in the finally of the else (basically like I do in my answer; see justification there), it is neater.

Comment: BTW, I like this solution: it is basically the same as mine, but it avoids the need for an ExecutorService. It could be tightened up a little (comment above, plus using `computeIfAbsent`), but generally nice :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you could do that by using a very high `permit` number (higher than the number of threads, e.g. 2000000).

Then in the function that should run exclusively you `acquire` the complete number of permits (`acquire(2000000)`) and in the other threads you `acquire` only a single permit.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the easiest way to do this would be using an `ExecutorService` and `Future`:

```
class ContainingClass {
  private final ConcurrentHashMap<String, Future<?>> pending =
    new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
  private final ExecutorService executor;

  ContainingClass(ExecutorService executor) {
    this.executor = executor;
  }

  void test(String hash) {
    Future<?> future = pending.computeIfAbsent(
        hash,
        () -> executor.submit(() -> longRunningMethod()));

    // Exception handling omitted for clarity.
    try {
      future.get();  // Block until LRM has finished.
    } finally {
      // Always remove: in case of exception, this allows
      // the value to be computed again.
      pending.values().remove(future);
    }
  }
}
```

[<kbd>Ideone Demo</kbd>](http://ideone.com/axsKZl)

Removing the future from the values is thread safe because `computeIfAbsent` and `remove` are atomic: either the `computeIfAbsent` is run before the `remove`, in which case the existing future is returned, and is immediately complete; or it is run after, and a new future is added, resulting in a new call to `longRunningMethod`.

Note that it removes the future from `pending.values()`, not from the `pending` directly: consider the following example:

- Thread 1 and Thread 2 are run concurrently
- Thread 1 completes, and removes the value.
- Thread 3 is run, adding a new future to the map
- Thread 2 completes, and tries to remove the value.

If the future were removed from the map by key, Thread 2 would remove Thread 3's future, which is a different instance from Thread 2's future.

This simplifies the `longRunningMethod` too, since it is no longer required to do the "check if I need to do anything" for the blocked threads: that the `Future.get()` has completed successfully in the blocking thread is sufficient to indicate that no additional work is needed.

Comment: I think this doesn't meet requirements

Comment: Note what I mention about not actually needing to run LRM in the blocked threads once the blocking thread completes.

Answer (score -2):

I ended as follows using `CountDownLatch`:

```
private final ConcurrentMap<String, CountDownLatch> map = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

public void run() {
        boolean active = false;
        CountDownLatch count = null;

        try {
            if (map.containsKey(hash)) {
                count = map.get(hash);
                count.await(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS); //wait for release or timeout
            } else {
                count = new CountDownLatch(1);
                map.put(hash, count); //block any threads with same hash
                active = true;
            }

            return runLongRunningTask();
        } finally {
            if (active) {
                count.countDown(); //release
                map.remove(hash, count);
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: in case when multiple threads would call run() at the same time, they would end up bypassing #containsKey and would put CDL into map. This block is not atomic. Thus you would end up with multiple calls of #runLongRunningTask()

Comment: OK you're right, so one would have to wrap this call in a `synchronized`?

Comment: Take a look at mine or Andy Turner's answer. They both solve the problem. Choose the answer that fits your needs most.